# Django Admin Look strange

Tags: python, django, django-admin

It's a new install of Django 3 and I get this admin look for the panel :

[image: django admin panel]

I have no error in the browser console

I have already done
`python3 manage.py collectstatic`

One clue :
To be able to see this admin panel without apache 500 error, i must comment :

`django.contrib.staticfiles`
in settings.py, under MIDDLEWARE

if `django.contrib.staticfiles` is called in MIDDLEWARE, I have this apache error :
 `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable,`

My css and js looks ok...

I can't find how to correct this view

Comment: seems something broke during the upgrade. Did you open the Django admin from an incognito window?

Comment: it is exactly the same if I open from an incognito window

Comment: Ctrl+F5 helped me in this situation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()
admin.site.enable_nav_sidebar = False
```

Add the above code somewhere in your main urls.py file
This issue has been raising in django 3.1.
It's not an error. It's just a new side bar being added therein.
Add the above code to disable it.

Comment: Kindly mark this as your answer so that other people on the site can find the solution faster.