# Django admin template bug

Tags: django, django-admin

Today I installed django==3.2.6 LTS for a new project, but I faced this template of admin.

[image]

And this is User Change template:
[image]

Is it correct or it's a bug?

**Update:**
following snippet works correctly with django==2.2.

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = UserAdminChangeForm  # The forms to change user instances
    add_form = UserAdminCreationForm
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('-date_joined',)
    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_display = (
        'id',
        'username',
        'cellphone',
        'email',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
    )
    list_display_links = ['username']
    list_filter = ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')
    fieldsets = (
        (_('Account'), {'fields': ('username', 'email', 'cellphone', 'password')}
        ),
        (_('Personal Information'),
         {
            'fields': (
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'avatar',
            )
        }),
        (_('Permissions'), {
            'fields': (
                'is_staff',
                'is_active',
                'is_superuser',
                'groups',
                'user_permissions'
            )
        }),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': (
                'username',
                'cellphone',
                'email',
                'password1',
                'password2',
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'avatar',
                'is_active',
                'is_staff',
                'is_superuser'
            )
        }),
    )
```

Is the glitch in the template related to my Admin class?

Comment: I don't really get what the bug should be. Perhaps it makes not much sense to show the hashed password, but with (parts) of the password hash, one can normally not (effectively) obtain the real password. I would simply not include the password in the `fieldsets`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Actually my problem is not with the password field. My problem is with template, I think template is loaded with some conflicts.

Comment: The `<<` suggests that you may have some merge conflicts?

Comment: @mx0 I don't have any merge conflicts in my code. I don't have any codes yet! just installed django 3.2 and faced this buggy template.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Kimor My problem was because I had 2 different versions of django running on the same port.<br> change you django port to something else than 8000.

Comment: Thanks, I actuallu found the answer to my problem on another post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66888536/12059179) if it can help anyone !