# Django Admin Panel Form Displaying in Background

Tags: python, django, django-admin

This is the first time I am seeing this problem in the Django admin panel. The admin panel forms are being displayed in the background, as attached in the screenshot, making it impossible to add/update anything.
[image: Admin panel]

The form is however visible at the bottom when zooming out the browser content to 25%, but makes it very difficult to see any content.
[image: Zoomed out]

Comment: It seems your browser is accessing kind of a mobile view and not desktop view. Check your browser settings.

Comment: @Marco I have default settings for my browser from the start and the admin panel is working fine for my other projects. I tried running it in other browsers as well. I still reset my browser settings and the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the code below in my project urls solved the issue.

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()
admin.site.enable_nav_sidebar = False
```

This issue seems to have been raising since django 3.1 and it's not an error. It's just a new side bar being added therein. Adding the code above disables it and solves the issue.

Thanks to @Dr. Mukama for his answer in [Django Admin Look strange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63398552/django-admin-look-strange).